# Antenna modeling software and tutorials

Tags: software, antenna, tutorial, modeling

I'm starting to learn about antenna theory, feedlines, and different types of matching. I can build antennas etc from plans but I would like to be able to design my own and understand their characteristics.  What software could I use to get started? Any tutorials? I'm interested mostly in high frequency and would like to venture into V/UHF, especially for amateur radio satellites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One book I would recommend to you is the [ARRL Antenna Book](http://www.arrl.org/shop/ARRL-Antenna-Book-22nd-Softcover-Edition/). With over 900 pages and containing both theoretical as practical construction examples this should give you a good start.

For antenna modeling software, one of the best programs is [NEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Electromagnetics_Code), which is free and available on most computing platforms.

The Numerical Electromagnetics Code (NEC) is a popular antenna modeling software package for wire and surface antennas.

How it works

> The code is based on the method of moments solution of the electric
>   field integral equation for thin wires and the magnetic field integral
>   equation for closed, conducting surfaces. The algorithm has no
>   theoretical limit and can be applied to very large arrays or for
>   detailed modeling of very small antenna systems. NEC models can
>   include wires buried in a homogeneous ground, insulated wires and
>   impedance loads.
>
> Models are defined as elements of wire or similar as an input text
>   file (typically in ASCII). They are then input into the NEC
>   application to generate tabular results. The results can then be input
>   into subsequent 'helper' applications for visual viewing and the
>   generation of other graphical representations as smith charts, etc.

There is also [EZNEC](http://www.eznec.com/) which is a windows program using the same computations but which incorporates a graphical user interface making it easier to directly plot data. Note that if you purchase the ARRL book it includes a special version of this program.